# setting Chrome's download preferences w/ Chromedriver (Python)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Python 2.7.3
Selenium 3.8.1
Chromedriver 2.35
Windows 10
I'm trying to download several different files from a website, but they have the same filename. I want to set **"download.prompt_for_download": True**, so i can programmatically type each file name when the file download dialog is open.
But it's not working (not even the download.default_directory), it's automatically downloading the file, without opening the file download dialog and it's not saving in the folder i've set. I have read a similar topic, but it didn't work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

import unittest, time, re
class Lalala(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://servicos.dnit.gov.br/dadospnct/ContagemContinua"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
    def test_lalala(self):

    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
      "download.default_directory": r"C:\\Users\rafael.kobayashi\Desktop\Vh\BR101\\",
      "download.prompt_for_download": True,
      "download.directory_upgrade": True,
      "safebrowsing.enabled": True
    })
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("http://servicos.dnit.gov.br/dadospnct/ContagemContinua")
```

Answer (score 1):

That prompt where you have to enter the file name comes from the system, not the browser, so Selenium cannot control it.  You would need to use something like AutoIT.

You don't show the code you're using for the download, but I propose that you set "download.prompt_for_download": False.  the files with the same name should appear as many times as you download, but with a suffix indicating a number (just as happens if you manually download and don't change the name).  If that doesn't happen, you could write your code so that with each download, you move the downloaded file to a name of your choice.

Comment: I have tried this, but there are more than 300 files with the same name (each day of the year). The problem is that Chrome has a 100 file auto-rename limit when saving files. After filename (100).jpg, the next file's name will revert back to filename.jpg instead of continuing the sequence (i.e. 'filename (101).jpg').

Comment: Then my last suggestion should work...write the code so that with each download you pull the file out of the download folder, or rename it.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by doing this modification:

```
def setUp(self):
    options = Options()
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
      "download.default_directory": r"C:\\Users\rafael.kobayashi\Desktop\Vh\BR101",
      "download.prompt_for_download": True,
      "download.directory_upgrade": True,
      "safebrowsing.enabled": True
    })
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    self.base_url = "http://servicos.dnit.gov.br/dadospnct/ContagemContinua"
    self.verificationErrors = []
    self.accept_next_alert = True
```